# Plotting a list of data in a file using GNU plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file which has random values between -256 to +256 in a file. Each entry is in a new line. I want to plot this file with the values in the file on the y axis. I do not know the number of entries while executing the plot command. Anybody know any way to do this?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190337/how-can-i-make-a-graphical-plot-of-a-sequence-of-numbers-from-the-standard-input

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, your file looks like this:

```
100
-120
248
10
-212
...
```

(I've used integers, but floating point numbers will work just fine...even numbers like "1.e-5" are Ok) If that's the case, you can plot it really easily:

```
plot 'datafile.txt' using 1
```

The x-values will start from 0 and go up to the number of lines in your file.  See `help datafile using` for more information.

If you want all the points to have the same x value, you can do something like this:

```
plot 'datafile.txt' using (0.0):1
```

You'll probably get a warning about a zero range on the x axis (which isn't a problem -- gnuplot did the right thing).  If you really want to get rid of the warning set the xrange before plotting (or while plotting...)

e.g.

```
set xrange [-1:1]
plot 'datafile.txt' using (0.0):1
```

or

```
plot [x=-1:1] 'datafile.txt' using (0.0):1
```

**EDIT**

Based on what you said in your comments below, the script you are having gnuplot run looks like:

```
set terminal png 
set output "waveform-hy1-00000001-20120501-160221.929.raw.png" 
plot 'waveform.txt' with dots # it shouldn't matter, but I always use a using statement just for clarity.
replot        # <--- a replot after a plot is probably not what you want here.
set output "delta-hy1-00000001-20120501-160221.929.raw.png"  #<-- Nothing will be written to this file...
```

A few comments -- First, are you sure that you flush/close your output file (waveform.txt) and your script file (temp) before plotting?  If the output is being buffered, then there is a decent chance that one of those files is empty when gnuplot goes to read it.  Next, having a plot and a replot without resetting the output file name is not (typically) what you want.  What were you trying to achieve with that?  You may have wanted:

```
set terminal png 
set output "waveform-hy1-00000001-20120501-160221.929.raw.png" 
plot 'waveform.txt' using 1 with dots
set output "delta-hy1-00000001-20120501-160221.929.raw.png"
replot
```

Although this will generate the same plot in two different files.  What is the purpose of the two different files?  Is there more that you're not showing?  Perhaps if you paste the entire contents of the file `temp` along with a description of what you're trying to do, we can be of more assistance.  (Also, you've mixed quotes in this script -- if you're writing the script in a c++ program, you should check to make sure that you properly escaped your quotation marks when creating temp).

Finally, what OS are you on?  There's a lot about using gnuplot on windows that I have no experience with...

Comment: hi mgilson.. yes that is something that i want to do.. but basically i was seeing how i can plot without going into the gnuplot environment, if i am making any sense.. so basically wat i did was create a file called temp which has the foll :
set terminal png
set output "waveform-hy1-00000001-20120501-160221.929.raw.png"
plot 'waveform.txt' with dots
replot
set output "delta-hy1-00000001-20120501-160221.929.raw.png"
plot 'delta.txt' with dots
replot

then from within my c++ code i call this with a system call like so:
system("gnuplot temp");

but this for some reason doesnt work.. dont know why

Comment: @hRob -- I've edited with some suggestions.  If the suggestions don't work, I would advise you to open another question on StackOverflow.  Each question should be self-contained with a good description of the problem ("this for some reason doesn't work" is too vague).  *What* doesn't work.  *What did you expect to have happen and what actually happened*.  Part of the art to asking questions here is to figure out exactly where the problem is (e.g. is it the gnuplot script or the c++ interface?) and then making a simple test that we can play with to hopefully fix the issue.  Good luck.